# Click event with confirm prompt call in radio input using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have problem with work flow, I noticed that it check radio button before that confirm prompt was called and some decision by user was made. I don't want this because in real app I will call some bootstrap confirm modal and when radio is selected makes ajax request to server(according this make some decisions to activate "next" button or not). Other words I don't want that radio will be selected before that user make some decision.

I put `debugger` that clarify this points of workflow, you can try it in jsfiddle.

**HTML**

```
<p>Send me spam: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam" /></p>
<div data-bind="visible: wantsSpam">
    Preferred flavor of spam:
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, click: clicked" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, click: clicked" /> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, click: clicked" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var viewModel = {
        wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
        spamFlavor: ko.observable("almond"),
        clicked : function(){
                debugger; // put as checked radio button whish was clicked
                var conf = confirm("Do you want check it?");
                debugger; // only here is conf is true
                return conf; // by this condition revert checked radio button back
        }
    };


viewModel.spamFlavor("msg"); 

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**That provide better understanding my problem:**

https://jsfiddle.net/stanislavmachel/8ew7cdxz/11/

It is possible to solve this problem? If you have question about my problem I will answer and clarify as soon as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Niemeyer's `protectedObservable` as described here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

It wraps an observable in a `read`/`write` computed that keeps track of two values: a temporary one, and a real, committed one.

Here's how it could work:

```js
// http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html
//wrapper to an observable that requires accept/cancel
ko.protectedObservable = function(initialValue) {
  //private variables
  var _actualValue = ko.observable(initialValue),
    _tempValue = initialValue;

  //computed observable that we will return
  var result = ko.computed({
    //always return the actual value
    read: function() {
      return _actualValue();
    },
    //stored in a temporary spot until commit
    write: function(newValue) {
      _tempValue = newValue;
    }
  }).extend({
    notify: "always"
  });

  //if different, commit temp value
  result.commit = function() {
    if (_tempValue !== _actualValue()) {
      _actualValue(_tempValue);
    }
  };

  //force subscribers to take original
  result.reset = function() {
    _actualValue.valueHasMutated();
    _tempValue = _actualValue(); //reset temp value
  };

  return result;
};

var viewModel = {
  wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
  spamFlavor: ko.protectedObservable("almond"),
  onChange: function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      viewModel.spamFlavor.commit();
    } else {
      viewModel.spamFlavor.reset();
    }
  }
};

viewModel.spamFlavor("msg");
viewModel.spamFlavor.commit();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>Send me spam:
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam" />
</p>
<div data-bind="visible: wantsSpam">
  Preferred flavor of spam:
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, event: { change: onChange }" /> Cherry</div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, event: { change: onChange }" /> Almond</div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, event: { change: onChange }" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>
```

Note that I've changed your `click` event to a `change` event. This makes it work for keyboard input. Ideally, you'd subscribe to changes of the `tempValue`, but I'm not sure how to do that with the linked implementation...

Comment: I will try you answer in mt app then I will add feedback. Thank for answer.

Comment: Thanks your solution help me.